# array iteration php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am a newbe of php and I have some problem to print some JSON content

This is my code

```
//Read text file
$json_data = file_get_contents('data/data.txt');

//Decode it
$obj=json_decode($json_data, true);

//Print array content
print_r($obj);

//Loop the array to write content
foreach( $obj as $Item ){

    // add comment to html list
    echo $Item;
}
```

my JSON file

```
[{"name":"ken"}, {"name":"barbie"}]
```

my output

```
(
    [0] => Array ( [name] => ken )
    [1] => Array ( [name] => barbie )
)
ArrayArray
```

how can I do to print only "ken" and "barbie" ?

thank you!

Comment: Please just read up on arrays...

Comment: Your question is getting down-votes coz there are lot of stuff around for this question that can help you. Please search for them and if you dont find anything helpful, then post a question.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
echo $Item;
```

To

```
echo $Item['name'];
```

Comment: Yeah, the OP is confusing things by naming the var $obj, which suggests the object notation will retrieve the value $obj->name whereas in fact it is an array $obj['name']

Comment: @Cups no he is not. He just doesn't know his array structure. He does not seem to be trying to access the data in the object form. So that's not the problem. But the naming of the variables is weird and inconsistent though. I'll give you that :)

Comment: Sry, just read the docs again http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php -- my bad

Comment: Yes, he or she must learn about naming conventions

Comment: @Cups np mate, At least you are reading the docs :)